# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class in Spring Boot test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mockito, spring-test

** Here am trying to test for one of my rest controller using @WebMvcTest , but am getting this error. please check and let me know if any mistakes

**My RestController Class under src/main/java **

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.gelm.portal.epolicy.*"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"org.gelm.portal.epolicy.*"})
public class EpolicyRestController {

    @Autowired
    private PolicyService ePolService;

    @GetMapping(value = {"/epol"})
    public String configEPolicy() {
        return "Hello , ePolicy";
    }
    @GetMapping(value = {"/allpolicies"})
    public List<Policy> getAllPolicies(){
        return ePolService.getAllPolicies();
    }
```

```
** My Test class under src/main/test **
```

```
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = org.gelm.portal.epolicy.test.main.EpolicyTestConfiguration.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {EpolicyRestController.class})
public class EpolicyWebMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc ePolicyWebMock;
    @MockBean
    private PolicyService ePolicyService;
    @Test
    public void ePolicyWebMvcTest() throws Exception {

        Policy policy=new Policy();
        policy.setPolicyNo("0123456789");policy.setPolicyHolderName("suresh");
        policy.setLifeAssuredName("sowji");policy.setAgentId("5510255");
        List<Policy> ePolList=new LinkedList<Policy>();
        ePolList.add(policy);
        when(ePolicyService.getAllPolicies()).thenReturn(ePolList);

        ePolicyWebMock.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/allpolicies"))
                      .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }

}
```

** My test configuration class  : under src/main/test **

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"org.gelm.portal.*"})
public class EpolicyTestConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EpolicyTestConfiguration.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `@WebMvcTest` and `@DataJpaTest` both come with their own `@BootstrapWith` annotation. You should only use of of those, each describes a different kind of test.

Comment: okay tq ..solved it